# How to avoid GAE write limit

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We are building GAE service which will have a lot of request.

What we need is user registration, and we expect more than one registration per second. That means more than 1 write operation/second. We are not planing to store users into ancestor groups since registration should return unique id for every user.

The rate at which you can write to the same entity group is limited to 1/s  I wonder if this restriction could be problem for us and how to avoid it?

Comment: You are not going to put all users in the same entity group, right? Then you shoud not have problems with write limitation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some confusion here.

Entity groups don't mean you don't have a unique ID for each user. Every entity in the datastore has a unique key, whether or not it is in an entity group. It's just that the key then becomes a composite of its own ID and its ancestor's.

However, since you don't want to use groups at all, this is irrelevant. In practice what this means is that each entity becomes its own group - and therefore the 1/s update rate only applies to each entity on its own, and not to the set of all entities as a whole.

Comment: In general .. if I expect more than 1 write/s is it best practise not to use ancestors? (I do not need consistency)

Comment: Every persistent entity must belong to an entity group, even if an entity is the group's sole member. Since we cannot expect to write to an entity group at a rate of more than once per second, this limit must also apply to writing/updating the same persistent entity.